# Laravel (hasManyThrough eloquent relation) - WhereHas with OrderBy working on localhost, not working on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, has-many-through

Laravel (hasManyThrough eloquent relation) - WhereHas with OrderBy working on localhost, not working on server. On localhost it working, it sorting (ordering) well, but on live server dont ordering well. 
**On localhost is MARIADB on live server is MYSQL.**

public function index(Product $product)

```
{
 $products = Product::with(['subcategory', 'subcategory.category'])->whereHas('subcategory', function ($query) {
     $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
     $query->orderBy('category_id', 'asc');
 }); })->get();

  return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: check php and laravel version of loacl and server as hasManyThrough is new feature of laravel

Comment: please check your raw query

Comment: @KamleshPaul the same php and laravel version on live is php 7.3 on localhost 7.2.8 laravel is the new 6.X i using on both...the same files

Answer (score 1):

change your relationship as below:

```
public function brands()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Brand', 'App\Product' 'category_id','id','brand_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $products = Product::with(['subcategory', 'subcategory.category'])
    ->has('subcategory.category')->orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->get();
 return view('products.index', compact('products'));
```

Comment: I got this error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where exists (select * from `subcategories` where `products`.`subcategory_id` = `subcategories`.`id` and exists (select * from `categories` where `subcategories`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`)) order by `category_id` asc)